# Only mapping to subset of a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Weird question here.

I have a bad situation with a database I can't change.

```
[Table("PROJTABLE")]
    public class Certifikat {
        [Key]
        public long Recid { get; set; }

        public String DATAAREAID { get; set; }
        public String Projid { get; set; }           
        public virtual StandardAndScope StandardInfo { get; set; }
}

[Table("DS_CRT_PROJSTANDARDSCOPE")]
    public class StandardAndScope {
        [Key]
        public long RECID { get; set; }

        public String DATAAREAID { get; set; }    
        public String Standard { get; set; }
        public String Scope { get; set; }
    }
```

I have an optional one-to-many relationship from Certifikat to StandardAndScope. However! It's only one-to-many if the DATAAREAID column is a certain value ("crt").

Do I have any way of telling EntityFramework only to map rows where the value of that column is crt?

Comment: So if the value is not "crt" you don't want to map it or you just don't want the relation?

Comment: No mapping at all if the value ISN'T crt.